# Cypress, how to prevent error like: Must be in a top-level browsing context

Tags: next.js, cypress

```
(uncaught exception)
SecurityError: Failed to construct 'PaymentRequest': Must be in a top-level browsing context or an iframe needs to specify allow="payment" explicitly
```

At the end of the payment process workflow land in a 3rd party website.

1. Either I would check the content of the url
2. or fill some data and let it navigate back to my site
3. but no way I would ask a warning

Which of the 3 is possible with Cypress and how?